# How to make this double line shape with css?

Tags: css, shapes, css-shapes

Is it possible to make that orange double vertical line shape with CSS? (see image bellow). This is for a testimonials section on my site that has to expand vertically along with the text.

Many thanks!

[image]

Comment: it's very easy. give me a minute..

Comment: http://jsbin.com/samirine/2/edit check this link.

Comment: @KheemaPandey Pandey - not good enough. they are not aligned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example is the best one, it doesn't matter what background they have, or the page has. it auto-expands. try to write text in the playground demo page and see!

### [Playground page](http://codepen.io/vsync/pen/FAxdq)

### HTML

```
<div class='striped'>
  <p contenteditable>
    Is it possible to make that orange double vertical line shape with CSS? 
    (see image bellow). This is for a testimonials section on my site that has 
    to expand vertically along with the text. try editing this test and watch!
  </p>
</div>
```

### <del>SCSS</del> CSS

```
.striped{ 
  font-size:20px; 
  padding:0 0 10px 3.5em; 
  width:350px; 
  position:relative;
}

.striped::before{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    left:10px; top:0; bottom:0;
    border-right:26px double orange;
    border-bottom:26px solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: Thanks looks great but I can't seem to get it work on my side. I'm using a normal css file so your SCSS might not be compatible or something or maybe I'm just saying something silly as I don't know much about SCSS.

Comment: @Tiago - well you can use google to convert SCSS to CSS. I can write you an example with CSS, wait.

Comment: @Tiago - it was done 5 minutes ago, check edit above. also look at playground playe

Answer (score 4):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/8fZLV/)**

css

```
#trapezoid {
    border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
    border-right: 15px double orange;
    min-height: 50px;
    width: 0;
}
span {
    font-family: calibri;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 20px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 500px;
    display: block;
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Cool but it doesn't expand when I type more text

Comment: change the width of the span as wide you like it from 500px to 1000px or something or even 100%, and also you can change the height of the trapezoid and span

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieve using `after` and `:before` pseudo element. However this example is not accurate as posted image but here is a way. Check the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/samirine/2/edit)**.

```
h1{
border-left:5px solid gold; 
padding:15px;
position:relative;
height:auto;
border-bottom:5px solid transparent;
}

h1:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:6px;
  border-left:5px solid gold; 
  padding:15px;
  height:30%;
  border-bottom:5px solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: Thanks however the second line should be higher than the first is it possible to make it that way?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bd2N6/)

```
div#one {
    height: 100px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    border-right: 10px solid orange;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
}
div#two {
    height: 150px;
    border-right: 10px solid orange;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
}
div {
    width: 10px;
    float: left; /* To make them appear next to each other */
}
```